# Spring RestTemplate not returning all Headers

Tags: java, spring

I am calling a service with postForEntity method, and I need data that is included in the header. When I check through Postman I can confirm that the service returns 4 headers ( "date", "content-type", "content-length", "link" ).

However after calling `responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, responseType)` the responseEntity only contains 3 headers ( "date", "content-type", "content-length")

Is there something about non-standard headers that doesn't work with postForEntity? And if so what is the fix?

For the record, I'm currently using SpringBoot version 1.5.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding another dependancy to my pom.xml

```
<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

No other changes to the code were made. It seems that the Spring framework by default only reads standard headers but adding this library gave it the functionality to read the "link" header that I wanted.